# Open a web browser as a pop up window from Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an outlook macro that triggers when the user clicks a button in the ribbon.

When clicked, the button sends data regarding the open email to my server via a post request (subject, to, from, etc.).

After that request is sent, the macro opens a webpage in the user's default browser using this code:

```
Shell "explorer.exe " & domain & "/create-new-matter/from-outlook/" & EntryID & "/from_outlook/"
```

The user can categorize the email in that page (covert the email into a deliverable and assign the deliverable).

Unfortunately, this way of doing things causes the user to constantly switch back and forth between the browser and outlook.

Instead, I would like to launch the webpage within a popup window that appears on top of Outlook itself, similar to how a MsgBox would appear on the user's screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a userform and add a "microsoft Web Browser" control (as long as your site is IE-compatible)

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I think this will work for me!